# Query from one table with relation to two tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Good morning. Looking for a suggestion.

I have three tables:

matches | MatchID | MatchDateTime | etc...
appearances | AppearanceID | AppearancePlayerID | AppearanceMatchID
substitutions | SubstitutionID | SubstitutionPlayerIDIn | SubstitutionMatchID

I am trying to display a list of matches in date order, that have involved player X ($id) in the form of either a full appearance (contained in appearances), or a substitution appearance (contained in substitutions). A player will not have appeared in a match as both.

The result would look something like this:

```
matchid | matchdate   | type
1       | 2012-06-30  | (sub)
18      | 2012-07-10  | (full)
24      | 2012-07-17  | (full)
25      | 2012-07-24  | (full)
28      | 2012-07-31  | (full)
33      | 2012-09-05  | (sub)
```

The variable $id is the ID of the player I wish to display this data for.

There are some other tables that have been included in my attempt below, which are there to enable some more match data, but this has been progress thus far, which returns no rows. :/

```
SELECT
  M.MatchID AS matchid,
  DATE_FORMAT(M.MatchDateTime, '%b %D, %Y') AS time,
  DATE_FORMAT(M.MatchDateTime, '%d/%m/%y') AS date,
  M.MatchPlaceID AS place,
  M.MatchNeutral AS neutral,
  O.OpponentShort AS opponent,
  O.OpponentID AS oppid,
  MT.MatchTypeName AS matchtype,
  M.MatchAdditionalType AS add_type,
  M.MatchGoals AS goalsfor,
  M.MatchGoalsOpponent AS goalsagainst,
  M.MatchOvertime AS overtime,
  M.MatchPenaltyShootout AS penalties,
  M.MatchPenaltyGoals AS pensfor,
  M.MatchPenaltyGoalsOpponent AS pensagainst
FROM    
  matches M, opponents O, matchtypes MT, appearances A, substitutions S
WHERE
  (A.AppearanceMatchID = M.MatchID AND A.AppearancePlayerID = $id) OR 
  (S.SubstitutionMatchID = M.MatchID AND S.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn = $id) AND M.MatchOpponent = O.OpponentID AND M.MatchTypeID = MT.MatchTypeID
ORDER BY
  M.MatchDateTime DESC
```

I am using MYSQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT
  M.MatchID AS matchid
  DATE_FORMAT(M.MatchDateTime, '%b %D, %Y') AS time,
  DATE_FORMAT(M.MatchDateTime, '%d/%m/%y') AS date,
  M.MatchPlaceID AS place,
  M.MatchNeutral AS neutral,
  O.OpponentShort AS opponent,
  O.OpponentID AS oppid,
  MT.MatchTypeName AS matchtype,
  M.MatchAdditionalType AS add_type,
  M.MatchGoals AS goalsfor,
  M.MatchGoalsOpponent AS goalsagainst,
  M.MatchOvertime AS overtime,
  M.MatchPenaltyShootout AS penalties,
  M.MatchPenaltyGoals AS pensfor,
  M.MatchPenaltyGoalsOpponent AS pensagainst
FROM    
  matches M
inner join
  opponents O on M.MatchOpponent = O.OpponentID
inner join
  matchtypes MT on M.MatchTypeID = MT.MatchTypeID
left join
  appearances A on A.AppearanceMatchID = M.MatchID AND A.AppearancePlayerID = $id
left join
  substitutions S on S.SubstitutionMatchID = M.MatchID AND S.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn = $id 
WHERE
  (A.AppearanceID is not null) OR 
  (S.SubstitutionID is not null)
ORDER BY
  M.MatchDateTime DESC
```

and consider reading about joins, because with specifying a list of tables to select from instead of explicitly joining them you can come to the situation when MySQL will chose cross join